# Meteor app — resetting a deployed app's DB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Is there a simple way to reset the data from a meteor deployed app?

So, for example, if I had deployed an app named `test.meteor.com` — how could I easily reset the data that has been collected by that app?

Locally I run `meteor reset`, but I am unsure of what to do in production.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

If you have your app with you you could do this in your project directory

```
meteor deploy test.meteor.com --delete
meteor deploy test.meteor.com
```

The first deletes the app so its all blank. The second deploys a fresh instance of it back.

Comment: Hey @akshat, do you think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214385/how-does-meteor-work/ should be reopened?

Comment: this seems like a bit of a hack. is there no cleaner way?

Comment: Will this code cause the URL to be up for grabs temporarily?

Comment: this has nothing to do with resetting an app data in production, and I don't understand why this answer got so many upvote

Answer (score 43):

one way is to login to the mongo instance yourself and delete the relevant data
so something like per collection:

```
$ meteor mongo APP.meteor.com
> db.users.drop()
> db.xxx.drop()
```

you could just drop the whole DB, but that would confuse their env and you have to `--delete` the app and re-deploy anyway.

```
> db.dropDatabase()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, you spared me a rebuild + reupload, thanks !

Comment: doing this in production with logged users is a bad thing!

Comment: @DotNetWise: You're not supposed to have a production APP.meteor.com. At best you have a beta there, and with it being a beta, people know to expect hiccups like this (if their entire account and everything they ever did being deleted counts as a hiccup. Imagine if Facebook did that - I wonder how many people would bother staying and recreating everything.)

Comment: Great suggestion - simply dropping a few databases was all I really needed to do.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old, but I just changed my collection name.  so in your `/lib/collections.js` file,

```
someCollection = new Mongo.Collection("originalcollection");
```

becomes

```
someCollection = new Mongo.Collection("newcollectionname");
```

this is assuming of course that your app generates the data for the database.

Comment: You haven't removed the old collection here, you just created a new empty one. If you did this in an app running on a server (instead of just locally), you will still have data persisting on your server inside a collection named `originalcollection`.

Comment: Yeah @krose, I recognize that, but the point is that it's easy and fast if you need to test something.  As others pointed out, you don't use `myapp.meteor.com` for production.  And if you did, you DEFINITELY wouldn't want to just drop a production database.  I do this strategy to safely try new things with my model without compromising data.  IMHO this response wasn't so bad that it deserved a down vote, as it's a much safer way to deal with production data.  you can then always drop the specific collection, as @dcsan's comment explains

Comment: seems like a quick hack you can use if you know what you're doing :) upvoted to balance the downvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can access your meteor DB as

> **production-db-d2.meteor.io:27017/XYZ_meteor_com**
>
> where XYZ = your subdomain

for authentication use meteor auth (username & password)

You can access it from **rockmongo**, **robomogo**, **mongoui**, etc tools.

To access from command line

First authenticate by typing username, password of meteor

> **$ meteor login**

Then

> **$ meteor mongo XYZ.meteor.com**