# How to delete the data when the project is deploy?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I just built the chat application on the meteor and deployed it with `meteor deploy appname`. Now I want to delete the data present in the application. As we know meteor supports `Mongo` database, I tried by `meteor reset` but this reset only my local db not the application. So how can I delete the data from the meteor repo?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583107/meteor-app-resetting-a-deployed-apps-db

Comment: thank you @Kristoffer K but is there any method so that we dont have to delete the project and re deploy it ??

Comment: Hi! I don't think so, as meteor.com isn't really meant for "real" production apps (yet). On for example Heroku you get more control over your app and the DB.

Comment: oh gotcha....thank you for your response and answer. @Kristoffer K

Comment: No problem :) These are the buildpacks I use: https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite (or with phantom-js): https://github.com/cwaring/heroku-buildpack-meteorite-phantomjs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is as simple as opening up a mongo shell to the remote database on the meteor.com servers.

all you need to do is type

> meteor mongo *appname*

where appname is the name that you deployed your app to.

once you have a command prompt you can can use db.*collectionName*.remove({}) on each collection to get rid of your data.

Alternatively you can delete your whole deployment from the meteor servers.

> meteor deploy --delete *appname*

Then redeploy

> Meteor deploy *appname*