# If I re-deploy in meteor, does it reset mongodb?

Tags: meteor

If I have an app already hosted on meteor and I re-deploy an updated version of the app, will all the values in the mongodb be wiped out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No if you redeploy your app, then your data will be kept intact.

It will only be deleted if you delete it yourself. See [Meteor app — resetting a deployed app's DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583107/meteor-app-resetting-a-deployed-apps-db)